# Excel add-in doesn't work in workbooks that are running on HPC cluster

Tags: excel, add-in, hpc

I'm currently working on a project that moving Excel calculations on HPC cluster, everything is fine, but later the business required to use some existing excel add-ins (some .xla files), I know that excel workbook won't automatic load the add-ins when running in excel container on HPC cluster. So I wrote below VBA script in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim foundMyAddIn As Boolean
Dim myAddIn As AddIn

For Each myAddIn In AddIns
    If LCase(myAddIn.Name) = "myaddin.xla" Then
        foundMyAddIn = True
    End If    
Next

If Not foundMyAddIn Then
Set myAddIn = Application.AddIns.Add("C:\MyAddIns\MyAddIn.xla")
myAddIn.Installed = True
End If

End Sub
```

And I put MyAddIn.xla in C:\MyAddIns on each compute node. This actually got the add-in loaded in the wokbook running on the cluster but the cells that used macros in this add-in actuall returned `-2146826259` ( which actually meant `#NAME$` ). The workbook was put in a shared folder, \cn01\HpcExcelSvc. Then I wrote below script in the workbook to include the link and add-in status in the returned data

```
Public Function HPC_Execute(data As Variant) As Variant

 Dim result As Variant

 // some other calculation code

 For Each lk In ThisWorkbook.LinkSources(xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
     result(1, 4) = lk
     ExitFor
 Next lk

Dim ai As AddIn

For Each ai In AddIns    
 If LCase(ai.Name) = "myaddin.xla" Then
    Exit For        
 End If
Next

If Not ai Is Nothing Then
  result(1, 5) = ai.Name
  result(1, 6) = ai.FullName
  result(1, 7) = ai.Installed
End If

HPC_Execute = result
```

End Function

I found the full name is `C:\MyAddIns\MyAddIn.xla`, the next parameter is `True` which means the add-in was loaded. But the link was not

```
C:\MyAddIns\MyAddIn.xla
```

Instead it was

```
\\cn01\MyAddIns\MyAddIn.xla
```

Meaning to say any cell which formula was =MyFunc() (MyFunc is a macro that I defined in MyAddIn.xla) then became

```
\\cn01\MyAddIns\MyAddIn.xla!MyFunc()
```

So I added another block VBA script in the Workbook_Open() to update the link as following:
If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.LinkSources(xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)) Then Exit Sub

```
Dim lk As Variant

For Each lk In ThisWorkbook.LinkSources(xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
    If Not Left(lk, 3) = "C:\" And LCase(lk) Like "*myaddin.xla" Then
         ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink lk, "C:\" & Right(lk, Len(lk) - 7), xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    End If
Next lk
```

`Right(lik, Len(lk) - 7)` means to remove the `\\cn01\` prefix. With this update, I got the link returned from HPC cluster as

```
C:\MyAddIns\MyAddIn.xla
```

However, still couldn't get the result of the cell which formla was MyFunc().

Comment: BTW, the cluster that I tested with had only one compute node, which was cn01

Comment: Have you tried using workbooks.Open("...Myaddin.xla") instead of using the Addins collection?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Same as using the AddIns.Add , AddIn.Installed.

Comment: UDF links to XLA are hard to fix: there is some XL hard-to-work-out trickery involved. Rather than fix the links can you fix the location by putting the XLA in \\cn01\MyAddIns\ ?

Comment: No that I tried before, didn't work. On the other hand, links like \\cn01\MyAddIns\MyAddIn.xla"!MyFunc() are invalid, no matter the path is valid or not, the cells always return #NAME? I think the link should always be starting with a local drive, like C:\xxx, E:\xxx, even we try to add an add-in that resides on a shared folder in the intranet, Excel asks user to save the xla file to %AppData%\Microsoft\AddIns\

Comment: I'm thinking to turn the xla to xll or merge the xla into the workbook, not sure if this is doable. I'm a beginner on programming with VBA scrpts in Excel.

Comment: XLL should work because the UDFs are registered. Also putting the VBA UDF in an ordinary module in the workbook should be OK.

Comment: I fixed the issue, I accidently modified the code loading add-ins when I trying to add some more scripts for updating links. The fix is to set myAddIn.Installed=False and then set  myAddIn.Installed = True 
after  foundMyAddIn = True  . See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/accelerating_things/archive/2010/09/16/loading-excel-add-ins-at-runtime.aspx